# problem with raspberry stretch network

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch

I have installed the latest version Raspbian, that is stretch
but I got little problem that make me confuse,

When I set the `/etc/network/interfaces` file with a static IP address, and it's fine. But after I restart the networking for several times, suddenly I got error warning like this:

```
[....] Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.servicejob for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
see "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl- -xe" for details.
failed!
```

And when I try to find my configuration by ifconfig command, I don't find eth0?

Comment: add output of `ifconfig`

Comment: You should use `ifconfig -a`, or better yet, `ip link`, if you want to see all existing interfaces (as opposed to just the active ones).

Answer (score 1):

You don't find `eth0` because it doesn't exist.

See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for explanation and solutions.

You should **NOT** set a static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces` file which is why it states:-

```
# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'
```

Comment: ok sir , thanks for the advice , i have try to edit dhcpcd.conf , and it's work great ,